# how to log data to text file on server side from aspx page without change in .cs file

Tags: asp.net, .net, logging

> I have aspx page with button.On button click i want to log some data of dropdowns to a text file located on server without change in dot cs file 
>   How to achieve this??

Answer (score 0):

If i am not cofused over your question my ans will be like that

## Jquery

```
$(function(){
  $("#buttonID").on("click",function(e){
          set fso = ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");   
          set s = fso.CreateTextFile("C:\test.txt", True);

           $.each($("#DropDownID"),function(i,item){
               s.writeline($(this).text/val());
           });
   });
});
```

Comment: @skj123 Please check my edited answer for creation of file .... then merge these codes according to your needs.